# Python fetch data from json file

Tags: python, json, parsing

I'm new to python.
I'm trying to extract data from data.json file.

How can i get "Files_Names" and "project_name"?
Also, how to manipulate data, "XX\XX\X" is extra string.

desire output:

```
File_Names = ih/1/2/3.java
             ihh/11/22/33.java.java
Project_name = android/hello
File_Names = hi/1/2/3.java
             hih/11/22/33.java.java
Project_name = android/helloworld
```

data.json

```
{
    "changed": [
        {
            "prev_revision": "a09936ea19ddc9f69ed00a7929ea81234af82b95", 
            "added_commits": [
                {
                    "Lines_Deleted": 28, 
                    "File_Names": [
                        "1\t3\tih/1/2/3.java", 
                        "1\t1\tihh/11/22/33.java.java"
                    ], 
                    "Files_Modified": 8, 
                    "Lines_Inserted": 90
                }
            ], 
            "project_name": "android/hello"
        }, 
       {
            "prev_revision": "a09936ea19ddc9f69ed00a7929ea81234af82b95", 
            "added_commits": [
                {
                    "Lines_Deleted": 28, 
                    "File_Names": [
                        "14\t3\thi/1/2/3.java", 
                        "1\t1\thih/11/22/33.java.java"
                    ], 
                    "Files_Modified": 8, 
                    "Lines_Inserted": 90
                }
            ], 
            "project_name": "android/helloworld"
        }

    ]
}
```

Comment: I was looking for how to deal with sub_dict entry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`import json` then use `json.load(open('data.json'))` to read the file. It will be loaded as a nested hierarchy of python objects (dictionaries, lists, ints, strings, floats) which you can parse accordingly.

Here's something to spark your imagination and communicate the concept.

```
import json
x = json.load(open('data.json'))
for sub_dict in x['changed']:
    print('project_name', sub_dict['project_name'])

    for entry in sub_dict['added_commits']:
        print (entry['File_Names'])
```

Comment: I was getting stuck on "sub_dict".. this is very helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can use this approach

```
import json

with open('data.json') as json_file: 
    data = json.loads(json_file)
    for item in data['changed']:
        print(item['project_name'], item['added_commits']['File_Names'])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this with `json` module

```
import json
f = open("file_name.json", "r")
data = f.read()
jsondata = json.loads(data) 
print jsondata # all json file 

print jsondata["changed"] # list after dictionary 

print jsondata["changed"][0] # This will get you all you have in the first occurence within changed
 f.close()
```

From here you can take it further with whatever elements you want from the json.